# Copy and Paste Weight from one vertex to another

Tags: vertex-weights

Is there any way to copy the weight of all bone of a vertex (say A) of a Character mesh and then paste the same to a different vertex (say B) on the same Character mesh? So that Weights for both A & B can become same.

Answer (score 3):

Go to edit mode, select all vertices you want to affect, shift select the vertex which has the correct weights (source, last selected) and click the Copy button in the N properties panel, vertex weights tab.

If you want to transfer the weights of some vertex groups and not all of them, click the relative folder button instead.

The applied logic is the same as many others functions in Blender: active to selected; active vertex will be white, while selected vertices will be orangy.

Be aware that this procedure will only add and/or overwrite weights, it will not delete existing ones which are not present on the source vertex, so consider if to clear existing weights before copying.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. However, could you please inform me that whether there is any scope to copy any left side vertex weight of a lefty side bone of a character to the similar vertex on the right side but of a right side bone. Say, vertex A is on Left hand and has a weightage of 0.5 for a bone Hand.L. Now how to copy this 0.5 weight on a similar vertex B but on the right hand, however, weight to be imposed by Hand.R. Concept is similar by copying pose from one side by pressing Ctrl+ C and then by Ctrl + Shift +V to paste the similar pose on the other side of a character.

Comment: As this site is intended, you should ask a new question about this different topic. Short answer: yes, there is.

Comment: As advised, above question is asked freshly. Kindly consider to give solution at this link please: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277268/143418

Answer (score 0):

Select the target vertex in Edit Mode then hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and select the destination vertex, and in the side panel (press <kbd>N</kbd>, Item section) choose *Copy*.

[image]