# Copy and Paste Weight from one side of vertex of a Rig to another side of a similar vertex of the same Rig

Tags: vertex-weights

I would like to ask whether there is any scope to copy any left side vertex weight of a left sided bone of a character to the similar vertex on the right side but of a right sided bone.
Say, vertex A is on Left hand and has a weightage of 0.5 for a bone Hand.L. Now how to copy this 0.5 weight on a similar vertex B but on the right hand, however, weight to be imposed by Hand.R. The idea is similar that is being used for making poses in a character, wherein, copying of pose from one side is done by pressing Ctrl+ C and then by Ctrl + Shift +V to paste the similar pose on the other side of a character.
Is there any way to weight transfer by doing copy & paste in the similar way as it is being done for creating poses in Rig as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Weight painting there are two different concepts of symmetry:

- X mirror will copy weight strokes on the simmetric area of the mesh, useful when painting centered bones, such as spine, head, neck, tail.

[image]

- X mirror with "mirror vertex groups" enabled, useful when painting limbs, arms, legs. This lattest works only if the mirrored pair of vertex groups share the same name, except for a good suffix, such as .left .right, .L .R, .l .r, and so on (check for the list of accepted suffix on Blender manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/naming.html).

[image]

If you have already made a vertex group and you want to create its mirrored tween, you can delete the tween, create a copy of the source Vertex Group, mirror it and rename it as the previously deleted group, using the vertex groups dropdown menu functions.

[image]

Be aware that all thoose functions work well only on perfectly mirrored meshes: if something goes wrong in an unsymmetrical model, you can try to use the "Mirror topology" function, which tries to set the vertices couples considering topology instead of location (try both options to see which suits better your needs).